# implement search bar android

Tags: android, android-widget, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement the uisearch bar  common to the ios in android. What is the best way of approaching this?  I have searched to no avail. Would anyone give a helping hand? Much thanks.

Comment: If you would provide more information, how does the uisearch bar UI looks like and what functionality does it implement, then you would get answer faster.

Comment: I apologize. For reference please look at this link:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529. Please feel free to ask  anything in case of a query!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the best case could be to implement the google search features available in android :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good solution:

```
 TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            lvAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    EditText filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

Comment: Amitay, please expound on the lvAdapter. What exactly is it and which class is it referring to? Thanks.

Comment: lvAdapter is the ListView adapter

Comment: Thanks Amitay, let me give it a try and see